# Given a sequence of n numbers how to count all contiguous subsequences containing a particular number.

Tags: combinatorics

Let a given sequence be - $1, 5, 2, 4$
then the total number of contiguous subsequences containing the number $5$ are the following six sequences:

- $1, 5, 2, 4$
- $1, 5, 2$
- $5, 2, 4$
- $1, 5$
- $5, 2$
- $5$

Comment: Can the number appear multiple times in the sequence or are all numbers in the sequence distinct?

Comment: yes, all numbers in the sequence will be distinct.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that the number in question can only appear once in the sequence.  Without too much loss of generality, let our sequence be

$$a_{-k},a_{-k+1},\dots,a_{-1},T,a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}$$

where $T$ is our target number that we wish to appear in all.

Imagine if you will, trying to place $\color{red}{(~~)}$ around our result with "$\color{red}{(}$" on the left side of $T$ and "$\color{red}{)}$" on the right side of $T$.  How many choices do we have available for where each of them go?  Does each possible contiguous subsequence get counted this way?  Does any contiguous subsequence get overcounted this way?

For your example: $1524$ you have two places you can place the $\color{red}{(}$, namely being $\color{red}{(}15$ or being $1\color{red}{(}5$.  You have three places you can place the $\color{red}{)}$, namely $5\color{red}{)}24, 52\color{red}{)}4, 524\color{red}{)}$.  For two choices on where to place the left parenthesis, and three choices on where to place the right parenthesis, by multiplication principle there are 6 total combinations overall.

E.g. $1\color{red}{(}524\color{red}{)}$ would correspond to the contiguous subsequence $524$.

For our general case, there will be $k+1$ choices on where to place the left parenthesis, and $n+1$ choices on where to place the right parenthesis.  The answer will then depend obviously on how many entries there are to the left and to the right of it in the sequence for a total number of $nk+n+k+1$ contiguous subsequences containing $T$.